# How to use cloud endpoints with multi module?

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to use cloud points to build my API(at local server).
But I meet some problem now. I add the cloud endpoints code at helloworld.py , like this:

```
class StringMsg(messages.Message):
    """Greeting that stores a message."""
    msg = messages.StringField(1)

class SringListMsg(messages.Message):
    """Collection of Greetings."""
    items = messages.StringField(1, repeated=True)

@endpoints.api(name='test', version='v3', description="FIRST")
class test(remote.Service):

    @endpoints.method(
        StringMsg,
        SringListMsg
    )
        # path='test',
        # http_method='GET',
        # name='test')
    def test(self, request):
        msg = request.msg
        splitted = msg.split()
        return SringListMsg(items=splitted)

api = endpoints.api_server([test])
```

According to Google's document, cloud endpoints have to be app.yaml. So, I put it at my app.yaml, like this:

```
application: blabla
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: helloworld_api.api

- url: /.*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
- name: pycrypto
  version: "2.6"
- name: endpoints
  version: 1.0
```

NOW, in my case I need to start three modules, so I use

```
dev_appserver.py app.yaml dispatch.yaml backend.yaml frontmodule.yaml
```

And I go to

```
localhost:8080/_ah/api/explorer
```

I did't see my API, and I get error:

```
Skipping dispatch.yaml rules because /_ah/api/explorer is not a dispatcher path
```

But I DIDN'T add  /_ah/api/explorer  at my dispatch.yaml.
Somebody help me please!!!

Comment: Which module is your Endpoints code in?

Comment: I use it with my app.yaml

Comment: What happens if you go to `localhost:8080/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis`?